# Best known inequality for the larger prime number of a product?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-factorization

We all know given two prime number's $b$ and $a$ whose product is $c$:

$$ c \geq b \geq \sqrt c \geq a \geq 2 $$

where, $ab=c$

I was wondering if the inequality  for $b$ could be improved upon and discovered:

$$ b \geq \lfloor\sqrt{5c + 4 - 4 \sqrt{c}} - \sqrt c \rfloor $$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function.

This made me wonder what is the best known inequality for the larger prime number $b$?

Comment: Where did you get $$\sqrt{5c+4-4\sqrt{c}}-\sqrt{c}$$ from?

Comment: It's a bit long winded proof. Is it alright if I answer my own question to show how I got that estimate?

Comment: That works - you can also edit your question to add how you got the estimate at the bottom or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bound is $$b \geq \sqrt{c}$$

This is because equality can always hold in the case that $c$ is the square of a prime number, since $$a=b=\sqrt{c}$$ This means that the inequality cannot be improved.